# debian apt error Could not open file

Tags: linux, debian, repository, apt

When I issued `apt-get build-dep openoffice.org` I got the error as below:

```
apt-get build-dep openoffice.org
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/http.us.debian.org_debian_dists_squeeze_updates_main_source_Sources - open (2: No such file or directory)
```

How to fix this thing?

Additional info: I got following errors on `apt-get update`

```
Ign cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.1a _Squeeze_ - Official i386 DVD Binary-1 20110322-15:11] squeeze Release.gpg
Ign cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.1a _Squeeze_ - Official i386 DVD Binary-1 20110322-15:11]/ squeeze/contrib Translation-en
Ign cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.1a _Squeeze_ - Official i386 DVD Binary-1 20110322-15:11]/ squeeze/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.1a _Squeeze_ - Official i386 DVD Binary-1 20110322-15:11]/ squeeze/main Translation-en
Ign cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.1a _Squeeze_ - Official i386 DVD Binary-1 20110322-15:11]/ squeeze/main Translation-en_US
Ign cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.1a _Squeeze_ - Official i386 DVD Binary-1 20110322-15:11] squeeze Release
Ign cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.1a _Squeeze_ - Official i386 DVD Binary-1 20110322-15:11] squeeze/contrib i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.1a _Squeeze_ - Official i386 DVD Binary-1 20110322-15:11] squeeze/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://ftp.us.debian.org squeeze-updates Release.gpg                       
Hit http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates Release.gpg           
Hit http://http.us.debian.org squeeze Release.gpg                    
Ign http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates/contrib Translation-en
Ign http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates/contrib Translation-en
Ign http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://ftp.us.debian.org squeeze-updates Release                 
Hit http://ftp.us.debian.org squeeze-updates/main Sources/DiffIndex  
Ign http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/contrib Translation-en
Ign http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/contrib Translation-en_US
Hit http://ftp.us.debian.org squeeze-updates/contrib Sources         
Ign http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/main Translation-en    
Ign http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/main Translation-en_US 
Ign http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/non-free Translation-en
Ign http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/non-free Translation-en_US
Ign http://http.us.debian.org squeeze/updates Release.gpg
Hit http://ftp.us.debian.org squeeze-updates/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://ftp.us.debian.org squeeze-updates/contrib i386 Packages   
Hit http://http.us.debian.org squeeze Release                        
Ign http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates/non-free Translation-en        
Hit http://ftp.us.debian.org squeeze-updates/main i386 Packages                
Ign http://http.us.debian.org squeeze/updates Release                
Ign http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates/non-free Translation-en_US
Hit http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates Release
Hit http://http.us.debian.org squeeze/main Sources
Hit http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates/main i386 Packages
Hit http://http.us.debian.org squeeze/contrib Sources
Hit http://http.us.debian.org squeeze/non-free Sources
Hit http://http.us.debian.org squeeze/main i386 Packages
Hit http://http.us.debian.org squeeze/contrib i386 Packages
Hit http://http.us.debian.org squeeze/non-free i386 Packages
Hit http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates/contrib i386 Packages
Ign http://http.us.debian.org squeeze/updates/main Sources
Hit http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates/non-free i386 Packages
Ign http://http.us.debian.org squeeze/updates/contrib Sources
Ign http://http.us.debian.org squeeze/updates/non-free Sources
Err http://http.us.debian.org squeeze/updates/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
Err http://http.us.debian.org squeeze/updates/contrib Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
Err http://http.us.debian.org squeeze/updates/non-free Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://http.us.debian.org/debian/dists/squeeze/updates/main/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://http.us.debian.org/debian/dists/squeeze/updates/contrib/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://http.us.debian.org/debian/dists/squeeze/updates/non-free/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]

E: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 1):

For this to work, you must have this line in your /etc/apt/sources.list

```
   deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
```

(this is for me, since I run wheezy, you should just substitute *squeeze* for wheezy*). Then issue the following commands:

```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get build-dep openoffice.org
```

to the second of which you will get the reply:

```
   > sudo apt-get build-dep openoffice.org                                                                                   
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   The following NEW packages will be installed:
      debhelper gettext html2text intltool-debian libgettextpo0 po-debconf
   0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
   Need to get 3117 kB of archives.
   After this operation, 8471 kB of additional disk space will be used.
   Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

That's it.

Comment: I already have that line in my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. But I am still getting the error.

Comment: @TemPora Did you run apt-get update?

Comment: Yes I ran it. I got the errors `W: Failed to fetch http://http.us.debian.org/debian/dists/squeeze/updates/non-free/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]` and `E: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`

Comment: I removed all lines of that server `[IP: 64.50.236.52 80]` from the `sources.list` and then it worked. Why `http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/` works but `http://http.us.debian.org/debian` does not work?